# What options in python to define your primary unix group for file/folder/links to be created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDITED on Dec.13th 3:00PM PST:
I have a python3 program that I used pyinstaller to packaged into an executable before deploying.  This program will allow an admin-group of users to setup/package an environment based on data that is in a restricted environment.

I have the followings:

1. Because it is access to a restricted area, the executable is owned
   by "app-admin" and will be run as "app-admin".  This was achieved
   via setuid.
2. The script should only be allowed to run by group:
   "app-administrators"; so I have the group ownership of this script
   as app-administrators.

So, I have the below when I do a ls -l:

```
-rwsr-s--- 1 app-admin app-administrators 10926616 Nov  1 11:38 myscript
```

Part of the operation of the myscript will be creating file, symlinks and folders; I like the group owner for those objects to be group "app-users".

The app-admin belongs to many groups including "app-administrators", "app-users" and other at the moment.

What are my options to do that programmatically?  Maybe what I did so far is incorrect?

I am currently looking at the 2 approaches:
Approach 1: run os.chown right after the creation, but I don't like the overhead.
Approach 2: Use subprocess.call() and execute the unix command usermode to change the primary group in the beginning of my python script.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually pretty curious as to how the POSIX-specified `newgrp` command sets egid to a secondary group -- that is, which syscalls it's using, and whether they're available in the `os` module; it appears to operate properly in situations where `os.setegid()` returns `EPERM`.

Comment: FYI -- edit history is publicly visible to anyone clicking [the "edited at" link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47783463/revisions), so you don't need to include it in the text of the question.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set the [`setgid` bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on the executable file so that it runs as the correct group. When you create directories you should set the `setgid` bit on them too (`chmod g+s`).

Comment: Just setgid, not setuid -- the OP wants to keep the user account, but run with the group owner as the effective gid. Other than that, I don't offhand see why this wouldn't work (be nice if we had a comment with the downvote).

Comment: Indeed, `setuid` isn't needed here (edited to remove).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can use `setgid` on a shell script.  Never mind... I see, he made a binary.

Comment: @jszakmeister, the OP explicitly says they're using pyinstaller to wrap their script in a binary.

Comment: When I created the executable file, I did the followings:

Comment: Sorry about the previous unfinished comments...  When I created the executable file as "special-userX", I did the followings: (1) Change the group for this executable to "special-group" and (2) use chmod g+sx on the executable.  However, this seems to allow any members of "special-group" to execute the file as "special-userX".  And when I looked at some of the file/symlinks/folders that it created, they can be different (although all of them special-userX belongs to)...  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your comment isn't clear. Setting the `setgid` bit means that the effective gid of the running executable is the group that owns the executable. Under normal operations, new files that that process creates will inherit that group, but of course that doesn't apply if the process explicitly uses a different group (e.g. if you use `tar` to unpack files with different ownership) or changes the effective uid (e.g. using `sudo`). I think you need to edit your question to give an example that shows the permissions you're getting and the permissions you actually want.

Comment: I am sorry, I got confused about setuid and setgid.  I will edit my original question.